# How do I shutdown an HTTPServer from inside a request handler in Python?

Tags: python, basehttpserver

How do I shutdown this server when I receive the StopIteration exception? sys.exit() does not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer

PORT_NUMBER = 2000

from itertools import islice
filename = 'data/all.txt'
file = open(filename, 'r')
lines_gen = islice(file, None)

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        global lines_gen

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/plain')
        self.end_headers()

        try:
            for i in range(10):
                next_line = lines_gen.next()
                self.wfile.write(next_line)
        except StopIteration:
            # return response and shutdown the server
            # ?????

        return

try:
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
    print('Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER)
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('^C received, shutting down the web server')
    server.socket.close()
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just call `shutdown()` in a second thread.

```
# return response and shutdown the server
import threading
assassin = threading.Thread(target=server.shutdown)
assassin.daemon = True
assassin.start()
```

Comment: As a one-liner: `threading.Thread(target=server.shutdown, daemon=True).start()`

Comment: how do you get the reference of `server` within MyHandler class? They don't have the same scope