# How to shut down python server

Tags: python, server

Used this code to run a python server:

```
import os
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer                                                                                                                                   

os.chdir('c:/users/owner/desktop/tom/tomsEnyo2.5-May27')                                                                                                                                                                                      
server_address = ('', 8000)                                                                                                                                                                    
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)                                                                                                                                   
httpd.serve_forever()
```

How to make it stop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop BaseHTTPServer.serve\_forever() in a BaseHTTPRequestHandler subclass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-to-stop-basehttpserver-serve-forever-in-a-basehttprequesthandler-subclass)

Comment: Are you on windows, linux, osx? How did you run it? In the shell using `python script.py` or as a service using systemd/whatever..?

Comment: "How to make it stop?" well quite simply by killing the process.

Answer (score 13):

Your question is ambiguous - if your running the server via shell i.e. python myscript.py, simply press `crtl + C`.

If you want to close it elegantly using code, you must decide on some condition, or point, or exception to call it shutdown. You can add a block and call `httpd.shutdown()` - as **[`HttpServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer)** itself is a **[`SocketServer.TCPSServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.TCPServer)** subclass:

> The first class, **HTTPServer**, is a **SocketServer.TCPServer** subclass, and
> therefore implements the **SocketServer.BaseServer** interface. It creates
> and listens at the HTTP socket, dispatching the requests to a handler.

So the `BaseServer` has a method **[`shutdown()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseServer.shutdown)**, hence being a subclass HttpServer has it too.

for example:

```
import os
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer                                                                                                                                   

os.chdir('c:/users/owner/desktop/tom/tomsEnyo2.5-May27')                                                                                                                                                                                      
server_address = ('', 8000)   
try:
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)                                                                                                                                   
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    httpd.shutdown()
```

---

Helpful relevant question -

- [How do I shutdown an HTTPServer from inside a request handler in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040055/how-do-i-shutdown-an-httpserver-from-inside-a-request-handler-in-python)?
- [How to stop BaseHTTPServer.serve_forever() in a BaseHTTPRequestHandler subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-to-stop-basehttpserver-serve-forever-in-a-basehttprequesthandler-subclass/268660#268660)?

Comment: From what I tested, it looks `except Exception` is not enough but It should be `except KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: @Alex this is true, the reason being `KeyboardInterrupt` extends `BaseException`, not `Exception` like most Python exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the Python HTTP server in a unit test then it is advisable to run it in a separate thread and stop it from another one, like this:

```
import unittest
from threading import Thread
from http.server import HTTPServer

class TestWithHTTP(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    My unit test that needs a HTTP server
    NOTE: skeleton code
    """

    def setUp(self):
        # you need to provide the host, port and request handler class
        self.myserver = HTTPServer((host, port), HandlerClass)
        # start HTTP server in another thread
        httpthread = Thread(target=self.myserver.serve_forever)
        httpthread.start()
        # ... any other setup operations ...

    def test_something(self):
        # ... your unit testing code ...
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        # shut down the server from yet another thread
        killerthread = Thread(target = self.myserver.shutdown)
        killerthread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very late but I ran into this problem recently. So here is my solution: create a class that handles tracking of start/stop of the server in processes:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer as StdHTTPServer
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

class HTTPServer(StdHTTPServer):
    def __init__(
        self,
        hostname: str = "0.0.0.0",
        port: int = 8080,
    ):
        super().__init__((hostname, port), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        self.serve_ps = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start_serve()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.stop_serve()

    def start_serve(self):
        """Serve forever in a new process"""
        self.serve_ps = Process(target=self.serve_forever)
        self.serve_ps.start()

    def stop_serve(self):
        ps = Process(target=self.shutdown)
        ps.start()
        sleep(2)

        self.serve_ps.kill()
        self.serve_ps.join(timeout=1)

        ps.kill()
        ps.join(timeout=1)

        self.server_close()
```

Then you can use `start_serve` and `stop_serve` to start/stop the server. Or use the context manager

```
with HTTPServer() as http_server:
    # <code>
    # server is closed when <code> finishes
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a SIGTERM signal from the handler thread if you are ok with killing the whole process:

```
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Answer (score -3):

Just use **^C (control+c)** to shut down python server.

Comment: It doesn't :( work server is still running in the background. You can test by visiting the site in the browser.