# Python3:How do I close connection opened by http.server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, localhost, port

I was using looking at the docs of http.server and ran the code:

```
def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Now I can't close the server running on port 8000 , How do I close it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shut down python server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763311/how-to-shut-down-python-server)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `^C` (control+c) to shut down python server

or use `httpd.shutdown()` in the code to close it.

See the detailed answer at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42763796/10241547

Answer (score 2):

The HTTPServer is a subclass of [TCPServer](https://kite.com/python/docs/SocketServer.TCPServer) class

When `serve_forever()` function is executed it periodically checks for the value of `__shutdown_request` variable. If its value becomes True, the `serve_forever()` function exits its main loop.

The `shutdown()` method sets that variable to True thus initiating loop break.